# C# select doesn't change value of array

Tags: c#, arrays, select, value-type, reference-type

Can anyone explain to me why this code changes Matrix internal array:

```
    public Labyrinth(int width, int height)
    {
        baseMatrix = new char[width][];

        for (int i = 0; i<baseMatrix.Length; ++i)
        {
            baseMatrix[i] = new char[height];
        }

        mod(baseMatrix[0]);
    }

    void mod(char[] x)
    {
        x[0] = 'a';
    }
```

and this doesn't change anything:

```
    public Labyrinth(int width, int height)
    {
        baseMatrix = new char[width][];

        for (int i = 0; i<baseMatrix.Length; ++i)
        {
            baseMatrix[i] = new char[height];
        }

        baseMatrix.Select(x => x[0] = 'a');
     }
```

I don't understand, both the select and the function take a char[] element, this i believe is passed for value, then x[0] should be modified in both case, where i'm wrong?

Comment: You do realize that your `Select` solution will unnecessarily set `x[0]` `baseMatrix.Length` times when materialized? Don’t use linq operators to produce side effects, they are not meant to be used this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you haven't materialized the result of the `Select` call. The last line of code is merely a lazy-evaluated expression. Since its value has never been requested, the expression has not been executed and therefore no modification was made to the array.

You have to do something, like call `ToList()`, to force the expression evaluate.

```
baseMatrix.Select(x => x[0] = 'a').ToList();
```

On a side note, you should really refrain from doing things this way. LINQ operators are intended to be side-effect free, and setting an array content inside a `Select` call can cause bugs.

Comment: I would never do this seriously!! it is a case study, I did not know there were these 'lazy-valued expression'; is this valid for every function that must return a value?

Comment: @Jujjizzu It’s generally valid for any iterator method. Linq extensions that don’t return an enumeration are eager; `Count`, `First`, `Last`, etc.

Comment: @Jujjizzu also, the extent of the laziness depends on the nature of the method; `Select` will produce results sequentially, enumerating the source enumeration one by one on demand. `OrderBy` or `Reverse` on the other hand will eagerly enumerate the source enumeration entirely when materialized.

Comment: Perfect, any doubt is clarified, thank you very much